# Can I read ibeacon data using Arduino?

Tags: arduino, bluetooth-low-energy

I am using an HM-10 module (BLE) and Arduino UNO.

My goal is to read data from ibeacons using Arduino and HM-10 module (BLE). Is it possible? I have not been able to find any articles on this. All articles talk about connecting your android phone with arduino. Any idea?

Comment: "My requirement is to read data from ibeacons near me using Arduino" , I can't understand what you are saying by that sentence.

Comment: My project is limited by cost constraints that's why I am using Arduino. There are ibeacons lying around which are constantly emitting some data (major value and minor value). I have to read that data and upload it to cloud using a GSM module attached to the Arduino. Does it make sense now?

Comment: So if I understand right, you want your arduino to capture datatooth from the Ibeacons with your bluetooth module?

Comment: Exactly and upload the captured data to cloud using gsm module.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you can do this however you should check the HM-10 firmware versions.

Look at this thread from January 2015 http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=288624.0

> JNHuaMao will be releasing a new firmware version this month that will
>   give the HM-10 the capability to be use as an iBeacon finder/detector.
>   It will be Firmware Version V536.

Also look at the JNHuaMao web site because according to the above article the V536 firmware is designed to do exactly what you need so they must have an Arduino example for you.

Edit: And note this pdf from above article looks very useful. http://www.blueluminance.com/HM-10-as-iBeacon.pdf

Comment: Of course anyone willing to put up with the buggy and absurdly priced IAR tools can put their own firmware on the board's CC2540 if they prefer (TI unfortunately does not publish the BLE libraries in a form usable with SDCC)